# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'map' ng2-paginate

Tags: angular, pagination

I am trying to implement paging with `ng2-paginate` in my angular 2 application.

I have followed https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination link and ended  up with the following system.config.js:

**System.config.js**:

```
/**
* System configuration for Angular 2 samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
*/
(function(global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
'app':                        '/app', // 'dist',

'@angular':                   '/node_modules/@angular',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
'rxjs': '/node_modules/rxjs',
'ng2-pagination': '/node_modules/ng2-pagination/dist'

};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'ng2-pagination': { main: 'ng2-pagination.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var ngPackageNames = [
'common',
'compiler',
'core',
'forms',
'http',
'platform-browser',
'platform-browser-dynamic',
'router',
'router-deprecated',
'upgrade',
];

// Individual files (~300 requests):
function packIndex(pkgName) {
packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}

// Bundled (~40 requests):
function packUmd(pkgName) {
packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}

// Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

// Add package entries for angular packages
ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

// No umd for router yet
packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

var config = {
map: map,
packages: packages
};

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

This is the error stack:

```
Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'
at ReflectionCapabilities.prototype.parameters (eval code:5006:17)
at Reflector.prototype.parameters (eval code:5191:17)
at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getDependenciesMetadata (eval code:13459:13)
at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getTypeMetadata (eval code:13420:13)
at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getPipeMetadata (eval code:13447:17)
at Anonymous function (eval code:13246:30)
at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata (eval code:13236:21)
at Anonymous function (eval code:13228:29)
at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata (eval code:13215:21)
at RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents (eval code:15845:13)
Evaluating http://localhost:53869/app/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:53869/app/main.js
```

`Package.json` also shows entry for `ng2-paginate` as a dependency.

Can someone explain why this error has occured. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone is looking for the answer don't forget to import all required rxjs extensions like
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`